# ADG608 PWM on analog input for testing

Tags: multiplexer

I bought an analog multiplexer, the [ADG608](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG608_609.pdf).

I want to test the output value on the D pin by sending PWM to one of the analog inputs, the S1 pin.

So if I test with a multimeter on the D pin when the address on A0, A1, and A2 sets for the S1 pin, does anyone know the maximum voltage that I can send to S1 using PWM? I don’t want to burn it .

So if everything is good I should get a voltage on the D pin, and if I change the address to S1, that doesn’t have any connection, I should get 0 V.

Any clue or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the datasheet:

[image]

Note that the range applies **even if the power is removed from the chip** in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes confusing to read datasheets